# How to version control Jupyter notebook files hosted in Azure to GITHUB?

Tags: azure, github, synchronization, jupyter-notebook

Folks,
I`m using Azure Notebook.
Created a new library and linked to my GITHUB account.
Can see the files hosted on my GITHUB in Azure Notebook Library.

However, If I amend .ipynb file in an Azure notebook.
Not sure what is required for the respective GITHUB REPO to be updated.

Any pointers will be of great help.